# Evopdf - means to resolve external resources without baseUrl

Tags: c#, html, pdf, evopdf

With [EvoPdf](http://www.evopdf.com) you can convert a HTML stream to a PDF with various overloads of the [HtmlToPdfConverter.ConvertHtmlStream](https://www.evopdf.com/help/html_to_pdf/html/M_EvoPdf_HtmlToPdfConverter_ConvertHtmlStream.htm) method. Now you have to pass a *baseUrl* parameter to resolve external resources (css, images, etc.).

My question now is whether there is a way to convert a HTML stream to a PDF without the requirement of having a web-server running serving for example the css and images that are external resources of the given HTML document.

I am looking for a way to convert a HTML document with external resources to a PDF without the need of running a web-server. Can I somehow intercept the web requests of the HtmlToPdfConverter instance an handle the request myself to ship the required external resources? (A concept similar  to [CefResourceHandler](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefResourceHandler.html) in [CEF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework)).

Is there a way to achieve this with EvoPdf?

**Edit**: Ideally not with writing the files to the local file-system (the URLS are relative to the HTML document).

Comment: `file:///c/whateverfolder/file.ext` also is an URL ;)

Comment: @Gusman: Good idea and in worst case this could be a work-around. But that's not what I would like to go for.